# Why Hibernate Search is slow? Even with few records

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I have a project that uses JSF 2, Spring, JPA 2 and **Hibernate Search 4.5.0**. This project is very simple but Hibernate Search is giving me some trouble.

The only part I use Hibernate Search is for indexing a Oracle View. This view, if I run a simple `select count(*) from my_view` gives me **5756 records**, that is not much.

Well, the first thing I did, was the entity mapping with JPA / Hibernate Search:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Field(store = Store.NO, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String user;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "phone", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String phone;

    //Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

After mapping my entity, I build a cronJob to index this entity. Take a look the method that I use to index my entity.

```
public void index() throws DAOException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

    try {
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(Person.class)
            .purgeAllOnStart(Boolean.TRUE)
            .optimizeOnFinish(Boolean.TRUE)
            .startAndWait();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("Error creating index", e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

And, after indexing my entity, I can search over many columns with one keyword. **The problem is when I try to search without any keyword!** My application has to return all records. But I thought, using Hibernate Search, this search would be extremely fast. My mistake!

The search takes **more than 40 seconds to return**! Here how I search without a term:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());
Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name", SortField.STRING));
fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

Comment: To start, turn on SQL query logging for Hibernate and manually run the generated query to see whether the slowdown is in Hibernate or in the database. If it's in the database, make sure the query looks sane and then use the DB profiler.

Comment: I don't get it. I thought after indexing the query (no matter the time taken to run the query in DB), hibernate search only uses the index and don't run the query again in DB. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hibernate Search will run a query against the Lucene indices to get the IDs of the matching records, then query the database with those IDs to retrieve the full data.  To retrieve data only from the indices, you would need to use projection.

Comment: Thanks for the information @RandomMooCow. Do you know where I can get good resources about projections to use in my projects?

Comment: Yep, the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections) should be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query execution is probably extremely fast (as searching without a keyword is very efficient), but the next step of execution is to load all the results in memory from the database and loading 5000+ elements from the database is never going to be fast, unless you look into caching of entities and queries.

If you need to load everything, that's not a full-text query but better performed by a standard relational query.
Whatever the query type -unless you use projections- you might also want to investigate the loading strategies that your model is causing. Often you can get a significant boost by adjusting fetch strategies of some relation, and/or enabling second level caching.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with **[projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-query.html#d0e3443)**! Thanks to [@chrylis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189885/chrylis), [@RandomMooCow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1260254/randommoocow) and [@Sanne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563323/sanne).

I had to modify some of my code. The first thing I did, was to change the way how to query the data to use projections.

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());

// I added this line to use projections
fullTextQuery.setProjection("id", "name", "email", "user", "phone");

Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("name", SortField.STRING));
fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
```

But, when I use projection, the query doesn't return a list of specific object (in my case: `Person.class`), but a list of `Object[].class`. So, I write a method to convert `List<Object[]>` to `List<Person>`. Here is the code:

```
private List<Person> toList(List<Object[]> objPeople) {
    List<Person> lstPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();
    Person Person = null;

    for(Object[] objPerson : objPeople) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.setId(Long.parseLong(objPerson[0].toString()));
        p.setName(String.valueOf(objPerson[1] == null ? "" : objPerson[1]));
        p.setEmail(String.valueOf(objPerson[2] == null ? "" : objPerson[2]));
        p.setUser(String.valueOf(objPerson[3] == null ? "" : objPerson[3]));
        p.setPhone(String.valueOf(objPerson[4] == null ? "" : objPerson[4]));
        lstPeople.add(Person);
    }

    return lstPeople;
}
```

And finally, I changed my entity to store the values on the indexes, so Hibernate Search can retrieve the data from indexes and convert to objects. My entity:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String user;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "phone", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String phone;

    //Getters and Setters ommited
}
```

**And it worked!**

Comment: You may still want to paginate thus you might want to look at: [`FullTextQuery.setFirstResult`, `FullTextQuery.setMaxResults`, and `FullTextQuery.setFetchSize`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/api/org/hibernate/search/FullTextQuery.html). Usually a blind `getResultList()` is a bad idea.